# Macro to copy certain rows from a worksheet into a new sheet and refresh all sheets each time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping you can help.

I have a sheet 'tender' which has a number of columns. The final column (k) will have a value of either 'likely', 'not likely' or 'no bias'. I then have three additional sheets, called 'likely', 'not likely' and 'no bias'

What I am looking for is  a macro that, when run, copies the contents of all rows in 'tender' where column k matches the corresponding sheet. i.e. All 'likely' rows are in the 'likely' sheet and so on.

Also, I need the information to completely refresh in the sheet each time the macro is run.I have seen other requests which look to add a new line to the subsequent worksheets each time the macro is run but keep the results from the last run also.I need the subsequent sheets to completely refresh each time to allow possible changes to column k in 'tender'

Hope this is enough information, I'm a complete novice so any help is appreciated

```
Sub LikelyTender()
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sType As String
Dim wsRow As Long

Worksheets("Overview").Activate
r = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row '
c = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '
Range("A1").AutoFilter


For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Overview" Then
        '
        ws.Activate '
        wsRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '
        sType = ws.Name '
        Worksheets("Overview").Activate '
        Range("J1:J" & r).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=sType
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, c)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A" & wsRow)
    End If
Next ws

Range("A1").AutoFilter

Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Ok, sorry. What I have so far is above. I know the issue is with wsRow = ..... End(x1up).Row + 1 because I want it to copy to cell a2 onwards rather than the first blank row under what is there already to show a refresh. Anything I try to change on that line, I get an error however

Comment: Not sure, are you wanting to clear each sheet (refresh) before adding new data, or, append new data to end of existing data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making 2 assumptions here, (1) All your sheets contain a heading row, and , (2) "refreshing" your sheets means clearing all previous data below heading row.  One thing to avoid when coding is to "Select" or "Activate" a sheet or range.  Rarely necessary and usually undesirable.  If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, this code should work for you.

```
Sub LikelyTender()

Dim rT As Range 'source data
Dim rD As Range 'data minus headers
Dim wS As Worksheet 'source sheet
Dim wT As Worksheet 'target sheet
Dim wsRow As Long
Dim b As Boolean

Set wS = Worksheets("Overview")
With wS
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rT = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'data width
    Set rT = rT.Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row) 'data height including header
    Set rD = rT.Offset(1).Resize(rT.Rows.Count - 1) 'data height wo header
End With

For Each wT In Worksheets
    rT.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=wT.Name
    On Error Resume Next
    b = rD.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 'check if data for this sheet
    On Error GoTo 0
    If b Then 'data exists, continue
        wT.Range("A2", wT.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Clear 'clear everything below header row
' This next line may not be necessary if new data always placed at row 2
        wsRow = wT.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find 1st empty row
        rD.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wT.Range("A" & wsRow) 'copy over data
    End If
Next wT
wS.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Could you please mark question as answered, thanks.